# Using Jooq with jsonb_agg on postgreSQL without code generator?

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq, jsonb

I would like to use Jooq with jsonb_agg in order to create jsonb objects I can read as a stream.  Is there a way to do this without having Jooq look at the database?

I know I can have Jooq look at the database and decide what aggregates it finds but is there a way to use this without going through that introspection process?  I have been through the docs 4 times and don't see an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the answer is buried in the DSL documentation, regarding defining fields.

All of the examples before use some variant of:

```
create.select(field("example1"), field("example2")).from(table(a)...
```

However you can define your own fields or even inline function definitions.

A field definition could be something like:

```
Field<Object> example1 = field("example1");
```

Or if you want to define a type:

```
Field<String> example2 = field("example2", String.class);
```

This becomes important when you want to define more complex fields, such as:

```
Field<String> jsonAry = function("jsonb_agg", String.class, example2);
```

Jooq really shines at allowing things to be composed like this.  You can then:

```
Fiend<String> fullJson = function("jsonb_build_object", String.class, example1, example2);
```

Then if you groupBy(example1) you get a nice jsonb_agg object out.

Comment: Thanks for documenting this. For future visitors, this is called ["plain SQL"](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/) and ["plain SQL templating"](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) in jOOQ